# Numpy Polynomial with Matrix variable

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, polynomials

```
p = np.polynomial.Polynomial((0, 0, 1))  # p(x) = x^2
x = np.array(
    [[2, 2],
     [2, 2]]
)
print(p(x))
    [[4. 4.]
     [4. 4.]]
print(x @ x)
    [[8 8]
     [8 8]]
```

Is there a way in numpy to work with polynomials, evaluate them at matrix point and get result produced by origin matrix multiplication as in second *print*, in spite of the result of first *print* statement

Comment: What do you mean by "in spite of the result of first print statement"? What part of the output you mixed in with your script was surprising?

Comment: @Grismar I expected p(x) = x^2 = x @ x as '@' is multiplication for matrices. So I expected similar output.

Comment: `p(x)` applies `a^2` to every element `a` of `x` (`2^2 == 4`) and `@` is the dot product for 2D matrices, which is not the same.

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I see, but Is there a way in numpy to work with polynomials and use dot product for matrices? It is important and should be possible somehow.

Comment: What do you mean "work with polynomial and use dot product"? Can you give an example of the type of operation you think numpy is missing? Dot product works correctly and as your own example shows, a polynomial can be applied to the matrix. Polynomials typically operate on scalars, the dot product is defined on matrices - it's unclear what you are asking for?

Comment: @Grismar I have polynomial over matrices. I want to calculate `p(x) = x^2`, where x is matrix and `x^2` is `x @ x`, not `x * x`. For example, I have `e^x = 1 + x + x^2 / 2 + ...` I want to calculate `e^x`, where `x` is matrix

Comment: I feel you're arbitrarily mixing operations here - you say x^2 should be considered x @ x. That makes some sense in that you're saying you need exponentiation of the dot product, instead of the scalar product. But then your example makes no sense: if `x` is a matrix, how do you propose to compute `1 + x + x @ x / 2 + .. etc.`? Documentation states that "Polynomial class provides the standard Python numerical methods ‘+’, ‘-‘, ‘*’, ‘//’, ‘%’, ‘divmod’, ‘**’, and ‘()’", so not `@` - seems pretty clear?

Comment: @Grismar For example, I want to compute finite sum `1 + x + x @ x / 2 + .. + x^n / n!`, where `x` is matrix. How can I do it better using python libraries instead of looping?

Answer (score 0):

To compute `x ^ n` for a matrix `x` and integer `n` using library functions:

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power

x = [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
print(matrix_power(x, 2))
```

Output:

```
[[8 8]
 [8 8]]
```

And if you need to compute the finite sum `1 + x + x @ x / 2 + .. + x^n / n!`:

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
from math import factorial


def compute_sum(x, n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        s += matrix_power(x, n) / factorial(n)
    return s


x = [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
print(compute_sum(x, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[21.33333333 21.33333333]
 [21.33333333 21.33333333]]
```

Comment: It takes a lot of time to compute `matrix_power(x, n)` and `factorial(n)` each time, but it is not really a problem, we can safe states to calculate next power and next factorial using 1 multiplication for each. The problem is - we are using `for` statement. Is there a way to avoid `for` and use more powerful C-written methods to evaluate such defined polynomials?

Comment: Since you haven't really told us what you're really applying the functions to, it's hard to say - there might be a more optimal way to do so, but it's unclear what data structure you're looking to apply these functions to and what determines `n`